# PDO SUM Query works but Returns 0 when a parameter is added

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sum

I have a PDO statement where I need to check the total value of a column which matches a certain ID.

Here's what I have:

```
$stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT SUM(debit) AS balance FROM pay WHERE rfid=:id");
 $stmt->execute([":id"=>$_GET['id']]);
 $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

 var_dump(floatval($result['balance']));
```

Generally, it works but when I added the WHERE clause, it returns 0.

An example of my database entries:

| id | debit |
| --- | --- |
| 8755456 | 100 |
| 9755000 | 88 |
| 8755456 | 100 |
| 9755000 | 99 |
| 8755456 | 50 |

The above query works without the WHERE statement but returns 0 when the WHERE statement is added. I'm expecting a sum of all the id matches but it returns 0.

When I run the same query in MySQL it shows the right value.

Comment: When sum returns 0 it means either the sum is indeed 0 or there are *no rows the id matches*, n'est-ce pas?

Comment: But when I run the query in MySQL, it returns the right value.

Comment: which exactly "this"?

Comment: That's the point, I am sure that the variables are being satisfied but it always returns 0 whenever I add a WHERE clause. I am sure there's a match but nothing shows.

Comment: A programmer should never be just "sure" or "convinced" or "inclined to think". But simply observe the facts. And the fact is, "the variables are NOT being satisfied". So you are supposed to find out where exactly they don't.